# How can I set the collection of one entity as the collection of another entity using jpa

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

I am setting up a maker checker system, and I have this Usergroup Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usergroups")
public class Usergroup 
{
     @Id
     @Column(name='id')
     private long id;

     @Column(name='name')
     private String name;

     @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
     @JoinTable(name = "usergroups_permissions",
             joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USERGROUP_ID",referencedColumnName = "ID"),
             inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PERMISSION_ID",referencedColumnName = "ID"))
     @JsonManagedReference
     private Set<Permission> permissions;

     //getter and setter methods
}
```

And this is my Permissions Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="permissions")
public class Permission
{
   @Id
   @Column(name='id')
   private long id;

   @Column(name='name')
   private String name;

   //getter and setter methods
}
```

In my usergroups controller:

```
    public class UsergroupsController
    {

        @Autowired
        UsergroupRepository repository;

        //create usergroup
        private void createUsergroup(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam Set<Permission>permissions)
        {
           Usergroup group=new Usergroup();
           group.setName(name);
           group.setPermissions(permissions);

           repository.save(group);
        } 

        //save usergroup changes
        private void editUsergroup(@RequestParam Long id)
        {
          Usergroup original_usergroup=repository.findOne(id);
          Usergroup temporary_usergroup=new Usergroup();

          temporary_usergroup.setName(original_usergroup.getName);
          temporary_usergroup.setPermissions(original_usergroup.getPermissions);

          repository.save(temporary_usergroup):
        }

    }
```

When I run the program I get this error: *"Found shared references to a collection: com.project.test.models.Usergroup.permissions*

The error comes from this line:

```
temporary_usergroup.setPermissions(original_usergroup.getPermissions);
```

How can set the permissions of the original usergroup to the permissions of the temporary usergroup?

Comment: Update: I've actually solved it by creating a new set and looping through the permissions in the temporary usergroup then adding them to the new set like this: `Set<Permission>permissions=new HashSet<>();
            for (Permission permission : temporary_usergroup.getPermissions())
            {
                permissions.add(permission);
            }` This feels like a hack though, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i.e nothing to do with JPA, and everything to do with Java

Comment: See here. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Explain your issue in terms of JPA and not your failing solution.

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for pointing out that link, I'm not sure, though, in this case, where I went wrong with the way I asked my question. Coz I did ask if _there is a way to set the permissions of the original usergroup to the permissions of the temporary usergroup_. It is only after I found an answer by trial and error that I commented, only that I thought my answer could be improved. Or what do you mean?

Comment: @NeilStockton , i think it's a Hibernate issue according to the Hibernate documentation. It says, _Two entities cannot share a reference to the same collection instance_. According to this link: [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html)

Comment: If something is an issue then you can actually post the code in your question that says this ... who knows what "original_usergroup.setPermissions=temporary_usergroup.getPermissions();" means without seeing classes ...